# Unix "$@" as parameter

Tags: bash, unix

Say I have some command:

```
somecommand "$@"
```

What is the significance of $@? It must be some unix trickery that I'm not familiar with. Unfortunately, since its all punctuation, I can't google it either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the current shell script's or function's parameters, individually quoted.

`man bash` says:

> **`@`**      Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one.  When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word.  That is, `"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1" "$2"  ...`

---

Given the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function all_args {
    # repeat until there are no more arguments
    while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
        # print first argument to the function
        echo $1
        # remove first argument, shifting the others 1 position to the left
        shift
    done
}

echo "Quoted:"
all_args "$@"
echo "Unquoted:"
all_args $@
```

This happens when executed:

```
$ ./demo.sh foo bar "baz qux"
Quoted:
foo
bar
baz qux
Unquoted:
foo
bar
baz
qux
```

Comment: You can btw find it by searching for `\$@` in `man bash`. You need to escape the dollar character.