# When is it necessary to quote a command line argument?

Tags: linux, command-line, command-line-arguments

When is it necessary to quote a command line argument?

Comment: Do you mean, "when is it necessary to place a command line argument in quotes"?

Answer (score 6):

You need to quote when it otherwise would be interpreted differently from what you might intent by the shell.

A few examples:

You'd quote the string argument `foo bar` to prevent a program to interpret it as two arguments due to the space.

```
# results in two directories, 'foo' and 'bar'.
mkdir foo bar

# results in one directory named 'foo bar'
mkdir "foo bar"

# you could also escape the space to prevent interpretation as argument separator
mkdir foo\ bar
```

You also quote to prevent some special interpretation of your input. If the shell uses `$` to indicate a variable name, `foo$bar` might get interpreted as `foo` if `$bar`is emoty undefined, or even produce an error.

```
bar=qux

# create directory fooqux
mkdir foo$bar

# create directory foo$bar
mkdir 'foo$bar'
```

As a special case, e.g. in bash, you quote `$@` (the current command's arguments) to make sure they're passed to another command *quoted individually*. [See here](https://superuser.com/a/362302/22317) for more information.

Comment: Always a good read: [Quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) on Greg's Wiki and [Quotes and escaping](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting) from the Bash Hackers Wiki.